# Getting username for PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I have a PFObject class where each object has a user attached to it. I can call each object and display it in a tableview, however when I try to call the associated PFUser to each object it just crashes.

```
PFObject *owner = [self.objectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *ownerString = [owner objectForKey:@"user"];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = ownerString;
```

Is there another way I need to call the user to get the username? In the NSLog the user looks like this: `user = \"<PFUser:dDeHnc33EE>\";\n`

Comment: What's the crash? You've left out the most important part of your question.

Comment: sorry! Error I keep getting is this: `'-[PFUser isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcc71ec8b20'` @CrimsonChris

Comment: That error is saying that something tried to call the method `isEqualToString:` on an instance of `PFUser`. `PFUser` does not have that method.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFUser is not an NSString, it's a subclass of PFObject which again is a subclass of NSObject. PFUser has a property called `username` which returns a string. Do this:

```
PFUser *user = [owner objectForKey:@"user"];
NSString *username = user.username;
```

to get the username of the user. Check of the PFUser documentation [here.](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/username)

Comment: thank you very much, I just need to add [user fetchIfNeeded]; and worked amazingly, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Remember, documentation is your friend :-)